# How to add and remove event listeners that are arrow functions

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add and remove event listeners using arrow functions. I'm able to add but not remove them. I've read the documentation and there doesn't seem to be any examples using arrow functions. Is there a reason why arrow functions do not work with removeEventListener? Is there a way to only add an event listener if it doesn't exist already? Ultimately that's what I'm trying to do.

```js
let bluebox = document.querySelector('.bluebox');
let redbox = document.querySelector('.redbox');

const clickMe = ()=>{
    alert("click added");
};

bluebox.addEventListener('click', ()=>clickMe());
bluebox.removeEventListener('click',()=>clickMe());
```

```css
.boxes{
  width:calc(25% - 4px);
  height:50vh;
  margin:2px;
}
.redbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.bluebox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="bluebox"></div>
  <div class="redbox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW, the problem you are experiencing is not specific to arrow functions. The same would happen if you used function expressions. You have to pass a reference to the same function object to `removeEventListener`.

Answer (score 3):

You are a creating a new callback by using the arrow function  ()=>clickMe(). removeEventListener cannot figure out which cb to remove. You can fix it by using the same reference

```
bluebox.addEventListener('click', clickMe);
bluebox.removeEventListener('click',clickMe);
```